# ORA-12505,TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descript

Tags: oracle, jboss7.x

while  running JBOSS Server 7.1.1 Final and Oracle 11G

```
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
The Connection descriptor used by the client was:
localhost:1521:orcl
```

while on VPN  and using   10.79.107.96  AMRITPC in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc>host file

can some one suggest the solution?

Answer (score 0):

First check if listener is up by executing the below command on the user who installed the oracle.

```
lsnrctl status
```

After executing the above command, you will notice the SID of your Oracle Instance, from here you can verify if your SID in your connection settings in JBOSS is correct.

If none of the above works, check your `tnsnames.ora` file under $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin. Check the `SERVICE_NAME` if it matches on your connection settings in JBOSS.